# dynamic_cast without RTTI

Tags: c++, c++14, multiple-inheritance, rtti, dynamic-cast

I have a structure like the following:

```
struct managed_object {
  virtual ~managed_object() { }
};

class trait1 {
  public: 
    virtual void myMethod() const = 0;
};

class trait2 {
  public: 
    virtual void myOtherMethod(int x) const = 0;
};

class MyType final : public managed_object, public trait1 {
 ...
};

class MyType2 final : public managed_object, public trait1, public trait2 {
 ...
};

class wrapper {
  private:
    managed_object* ptr;
  public:
    template<typename T> T* object() const { 
      return dynamic_cast<T*>(data.ptr); 
    }
};
```

So basically I have a `managed_object` base class from which multiple types inherit. Each of this subtypes can inherit from any combination of traits and they are `final` so that I'm sure they won't have any deeper level on inheritance.

The code works thanks to RTTI which takes the load of gluing everything together but at a price, otherwise

```
wrapper w = ...
trait* asTrait1 = w.object<trait1>;
```

wouldn't work because there's no direct relation between `managed_object` and `trait1` types.

In my complete code I'm already sure that all `dynamic_cast` won't fail because I have additional data (not shown in the example) which provides me a sort of RTTI that is needed for other parts of the code.

Given that, is there a common pattern to solve the *side*-downcast problem without using the need of `dynamic_cast` and RTTI assuming that I can already know that a `MyType` class is inheriting from a specific `trait`? I'm trying to find a clever solution since it's a heavy bottleneck of the code.

Comment: In the base class, you could add dozens (hundreds?) of getter-casters like `virtual Foo* AsFoo() { return nullptr; }` and then in Foo put in `Foo* AsFoo() override { return this; }`.

Comment: How do you know its a heavy bottleneck of the code? Have you made a profiling without RTTI to verify it?

Comment: @marcinj: I can't profile it without `dynamic_cast` because I have no solution to it but yes I profiled how much time is spent in `dynamic_cast`-ing so I'm already sure it's quite a bottleneck

Comment: Have you considered replacing `wrapper` with `std::unique_ptr`? It would mean that you can use `std::unique_ptr<MyType1>` or `std::unique_ptr<MyType2>` with full type safety in those (ideally few) places where the exact derived type matters, and then you can always cast that to a `std::unique_ptr<managed_object>` for generic code.

Comment: seems like curiously recurring template pattern(CRTP) is the way to go.

Answer (score 5):

You *cannot* use `dynamic_cast` without RTTI. Except for a few corner cases.

You *can* use `static_cast` or `reinterpret_cast` (please don't) though, but then it's on *you* if you get it wrong - then you can no longer test for `nullptr` to see if the cast succeeded

Comment: That's the point, I don't want to use `dynamic_cast` at all, if it wasn't clear by my question. I want to find a solution without the need of `dynamic_cast` and RTTI.

Comment: Actually you can as long as no runtime lookup is necessary. That is casting to base class or casting to const-qualified version of the same class is fine.

Comment: `static_cast` will not cast a `managed_object` to a `trait1`. That's what the OP means by "the *side-downcast* problem". `reinterpret_cast` will, but modifying the object afterwards is UB because the two types are not related.

Answer (score 1):

First things first: You have to use `static_cast`. `reinterpret_cast` isn't really suitable for this.

But in order for the cast to work, your program needs to know where it is going. By that I mean, it needs to know the path it must take to cast from `A` to `B`. If `A` and `B` are on the same class hierarchy, this is simple: just follow said class hierarchy to perform the cast.

But if you have:

```
struct C: A, B {};
```

And this is the only relation between `A` and `B`, `static_cast` has no way of knowing about `C` (this is the kind of information provided by RTTI), and hence it cannot perform the cast, since `A` and `B` are not really related.

In order to provide that path, you have to enable your program to know it somehow. The easiest way is templating `wrapper`:

```
template<typename T>
class wrapper {
  managed_object* ptr;
public:
  template<typename Trait> Trait* object() const { 
    return static_cast<Trait*>(static_cast<T*>(ptr)); 
  }
};
```

Then:

```
MyType a;
wrapper<MyType> w{&a};
trait1* asTrait1 = w.object<trait1>(); // OK
```

Note that I'm telling exactly how to do the cast, by first downcasting to the derived type, then "upcasting" back to the trait.

### A note about `reinterpret_cast`

If you are converting from a class to its Base (`MyType` to `trait1`), `dynamic_cast` will return *a pointer or reference to the base class subobject within the derived object* (`static_cast` can also make this conversion properly). This means that the value of the returned pointer may actually be different than the value of the provided pointer. `reinterpret_cast` will never make such a change to the pointer value. It will merely reinterpret whatever is passed to it as the new type, which is clearly wrong. The obvious conclusion is to not use `reinterpret_cast` to perform casts within class hierarchies.